# Notice: Undefined index: perfil in C:,

Tags: php

Al probar un sistema de inventario me esta arrojando un, estoy perdido ya que estoy comenzando espero me puedan ayudar con el tema

```
    </div> 
     <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
          <?php
          if($_SESSION["perfil"] =="Administrador"){
           include "reportes/grafico-ventas.php";
          }
          ?>
```

Comment: Saludos. A salvedad lo omitieras (pero si lo tienes); te sugiero primero revisar lo que necesitas hacer para que `$_SESSION` (https://www.php.net/manual/es/reserved.variables.session.php) esté disponible. Con lo anterior bien; entonces falta que revises, que momentos antes de llegar al PHP que contiene el código que compartes en algún momento `perfil` es creado y/o asignado para que al querer usarlo este disponible. Esto (entiendo) puede ser al momento del logeo/autenticación.

Comment: coloca el codigo completo, todo el archivo,creo que no estas inicializando la sesion

Answer (score 0):

## Tablero
      
      Panel de Control

```
<ol class="breadcrumb">
  
  <li><a href="inicio"><i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i> Inicio</a></li>
  
  <li class="active">Tablero</li>

</ol>
```

```
<div class="row">
  
<?php

if($_SESSION["perfil"] =="Administrador"){

  include "inicio/cajas-superiores.php";

}

?>

</div> 

 <div class="row">
   
    <div class="col-lg-12">

      <?php
      

      if($_SESSION["perfil"] =="Administrador"){
      
       include "reportes/grafico-ventas.php";

      }

      ?>

    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-6">

      <?php

      if($_SESSION["perfil"] =="Administrador"){
      
       include "reportes/productos-mas-vendidos.php";

     }

      ?>

    </div>

     <div class="col-lg-6">

      <?php

      if($_SESSION["perfil"] =="Administrador"){
      
       include "inicio/productos-recientes.php";

     }

      ?>

    </div>

     <div class="col-lg-12">
       
      <?php

      if($_SESSION["perfil"] =="Especial" || $_SESSION["perfil"] =="Vendedor"){

         echo '<div class="box box-success">

         <div class="box-header">

         <h1>Bienvenid@ ' .$_SESSION["nombre"].'</h1>

         </div>

         </div>';

      }

      ?>

     </div>

 </div>
```